# I have an error in my server FiveM and I don't know how fix it please anyone know how fix?

Tags: server, lua, localhost, fivem

I have an error in my server FiveM and I don't know how fix it anyone can help me?

Error in Fivem

[image: 1]

In .LUA

[image: 2]

Comment: don't share screenshots of code. text is shared as text...

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to add to the error message. You're indexing a nil value `PlayerData`.

Indexing nil values doesn't make any sense.

To avoid this error only index PlayerData if it exists or make sure it exists in the first place.

This probably happens because events are triggered in the wrong order. But nevertheless you shouldn't process data that might not be available.

Comment: but then I have to change or remove something?

Comment: @TommasoRizzeri of course or you skip the event if PlayerData is nil. what is `xPlayer` in line 41?

Comment: and how do i skip the event? @piglet

Comment: @TommasoRizzeri `if not PlayerData then return end` should do. maybe you should do a Lua beginners tutorial befor scripting Lua?